What is this show that features "pokemon" style battles and reality?
Roughly 10 years ago, there used to be this cartoon show about a game that the protagonist and his (2?) friends play. The protagonist is a white male. He enters this world, via the game, were its almost like the Matrix, being plugged in. You can trek the game world, and like Pokemon, capture the various monsters around, building up your team.
And like Pokemon, the monsters are controlled by you in battles that you set up with other players. The friends, if I can remember correctly were the standard one male dorky friend, and the female, possible love-interest. The characters were teens, as I recall schools in the show. 
If I remember correctly, the protagonist's main monster was rare(?) and quite powerful.
At some point in the show, I think the players got "locked in", as the game wouldn't allow anyone to leave the reality. 
Another point was when the game was brought into the real world(?)
This was an American production. I say American, because it could've have been Canadian or from the US. But is was definitely in English. Late 2000's. American. Cartoon. I know there are anime shows like Sword Art Online that sound like this, but it isn't anime. It is/was a cartoon for the 10+ year old demo-graphs. And it isn't Mix Master, Beyblade, Digimon, etc...
Please could you help me with this one? As I would like to watch it again and see how it panned out.
EDIT:
Remembered some details. And adding from the comments
There was some sort of catch-phrase that the main character shouted. Before each battle I think.
It was purely American, as the style was cartoon. Not anime or anime influenced. As far as I know about European animation, it wasn't styled as such.
I think the game was similar to something they played, and then the characters find out a way to go into the actual game world.
The main character's monster was a leader of some sorts. All monsters were capable of speech and thought. Often that would be the case in the battles. I think when facing someone, you could choose a setting/place for the battle, further enhancing the odds in the favour of the own challenged(?)
The main monster look mean, like an Orc or Goblin. And there was some other creature/monster that had to look like a lion, as I remember that also.
The main characters friend did wear glasses. And there was a female friend, although I think the main character meet the additional friends after entering the game world. He had the friend with the glasses from before.
It aired in my home country of South Africa on Mnet, from 3pm-4pm as this was the time for children and teen shows such as Avatar, Dragon Booster, Un-fabulous. Those shows were on that time. It was certainly during 2006-2007. 

Could it be Monster Rancher?

@Majuj no it is not. nothing so comical. it had a certain darkness to it, more seriousness than most of these shows.

Sounds like Code Lyoko, minus the capturing aspect. Maybe Yugio DX? Or one of the later Digimon, where they stayed in the real world most of the time? Describe the main characters monster.

@cde not any of those shows. like i said, it wasn't anime or influenced by anime. it was American. the main guys monster was... big. voiced by what sounded like a black male. i think he was either brown, like a lion, or he was black. they all spoke to each other, had an understanding, which helped in the battling aspect. i really wish i could give you more, but i can't transport the images out of my head :)

if it helps, it was on around the same time as Dragon Booster. no idea if it was the same production people or anything. i watched it on TV in my home country of South Africa, on a channel called Mnet, and it was on around 3pm-4pm, the time allocated for kids and teens

Code lyoko is french animation, not anime. But I'm assuming you mean the animation had very western body shapes?

@cde yes. although it wasn't eastern animation, i guess you can't rule out the possibility of it being European.

i can remember something the gamers shout out, just before a battle or entering the game world. similar to YuGi-Oh, when they shout out before a duel. this show shouted out something. the main guy/protagonist shouts it out. and i want to say the main monster might even be some leader or something like that.

found it! after all these years.
Chaotic

Chaotic (TV series)
Taken from the Wikipedia page:

Chaotic tells the tale of a teenage boy named Tom and his friend Kaz. They both play the Chaotic Trading Card/Online Game. Kaz always tries to tell Tom about a secret code to play for real which Tom refuses to believe. While playing online Tom receives the special password. When he enters the password into his game scanner he is transported to a place called Chaotic that is able to take him to another world where the characters, locations and items in the card game came to life.

The characters I described in the question matched with what I found. The friend has glasses. Main guy's "monster" is tough, orcish looking and a leader of his tribe. I found a clip where they shout "Let's get Chaotic!", which I remember them shouting. Similar to Pokemon, they scan monsters in to add to the team, then let the monsters battle others in a setting.
